# re-IP'd Chef Server and now can't authenticate

Tags: certificate, chef-infra

We've recently moved our Chef server from 'dev' to 'prod' and basic things (knife node list, for example) seemed to work OK.

This morning I went to bootstrap a new node and received the following error:

```
$ knife bootstrap <IP> -N devops
...
================================================================================
Chef encountered an error attempting to load the node data for "devops"
================================================================================

Authentication Error:
---------------------
Failed to authenticate to the chef server (http 401).

Server Response:
----------------
 Failed to authenticate as 'devops'. Ensure that your node_name and client key are correct.
...
```

Do I have to somehow regenerate keys on the server to complete the move to 'prod'?

Comment: Double check that you don't already have a node with that name.

Comment: No nodes or clients by the name ..
    `$ knife node list | grep devops`
    `$ knife client list | grep devops`

... and bootstrap results in the same error

Comment: Are you using the validator? https://docs.chef.io/chef_private_keys.html#chef-validator

Comment: @KenBrittain, I am using a validator. knife.rb specifies chef-validator and the resulting client.rb on the node being bootstrapped also contains the same validator. Do I need to reset the validation key because of the IP change?